# url rewrite in setup script only applies to default store view of id 1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

This method only applies the url rewrite to store of id 1 when I checked `url_rewrite` table.

Before I call the removeSuffix() method I also create 2 more store views in a method, but none of them are used for url rewrite.

```
public function removeSuffix()
{
    $this->_appState->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

    $config = $this->_configFactory->create();
    $config->setDataByPath('catalog/seo/product_url_suffix', '');
    $config->save();

    $config = $this->_configFactory->create();
    $config->setDataByPath('catalog/seo/category_url_suffix', '');
    $config->save();
}
```

[image]

How do I get the url rewrite to apply to all stores in the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use backend model of url suffix (see `app/code/Magento/CatalogUrlRewrite/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`):

*\Magento\Catalog\Model\System\Config\Backend\Catalog\Url\Rewrite\Suffix*

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\System\Config\Backend\Catalog\Url\Rewrite\Suffix $urlRewriteSuffix */
$urlRewriteSuffix->load('catalog/seo/product_url_suffix', 'path');
$urlRewriteSuffix->setValue('');
$urlRewriteSuffix->save();
```

But before run this, be sure that config data was initialized with default values (e.g. just save system configuration in admin)